# Laravel bulk update with bindings

Tags: php, sql, mysql, laravel

I want to make a bulk update to my `users` table. I am not updating multiple rows to the same field value - each field value could be different as it will be supplied from user input.

I want to batch my updates and use a single sql connection to send multiple update statements.

Laravel `unprepared` works fine but it doesn't bind parameters:

```
DB::unprepared("
UPDATE users set name = 'test1' where id = 43;
UPDATE users set name = 'test2' where id = 54;
");
```

Where `test1` & `test2` are variables which have been supplied via user input and therefore need to be bound before executing this sql statement.

I don't want to sanitise these manually. Is there a way I can bind these parameters through a php/laravel function, but also use this type of bulk update?

Comment: what you are using in your question is not a bulk update. It is still two separate queries sent in the same method `unprepared`. wouldn't make much difference if it was in a PHP loop

Comment: The difference is that `DB::unprepared` opens only one database connection, whereas using a standard `DB::update` will open a new connection for each statement. It will make a big difference at scale.

Comment: Why not use a transaction for this?

Comment: Wrapping DB::update in a for loop would still connect to the database every iteration. I want to batch the statements together so they can all be run at the same time.

Comment: "would still connect to the database every iteration" - no, the database connection is the same for all request, unless you implemented some really strange connector

Comment: The same database connection would be used however sql would be executed each iteration, which would be significantly slower than executing a batch of sql updates.